# Using Ethernet cable in SFP+ Port

Tags: sfp

Can you use an Ethernet cable (Cat6) in a switch's SFP+ port to connect to another switch?

Comment: In the port itself, or in the SFP transceiver which is plugged into the port?

Comment: plugging a cat 6 cable into the switches SFP+ port and then connecting to the other switches SFP+ port

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have compatible SFP-T transceivers, Yes.

Answer (score 1):

An SFP(+) port requires a PHY module unless it's used with a direct-attach cable (DAC) that has fixed SFP+ modules at its ends.

Not all SFP/SFP+ ports support 1000BASE-T modules. Quite a few SFP+ ports don't support 10GBASE-T (and if they do the reach is normally reduced to 30 m or so).

In any case, you'll need to check the device documentation for compatible modules. Most vendors also try to force you to use "original" modules, so you'll make sure the module at hand shows the required brand as well.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to put an SFP transceiver in the port, and then you plug the cable into the transceiver.

A RJ45 (Ethernet) connector will kinda fit in a SFP+ port, but it won't work because the wires won't get connected. It's like plugging USB into an Ethernet (RJ45) port.

Comment: if both switches have a Copper Combo SFP Port would that work?

Comment: Most combo/dual-personality ports don't accept TP SFP modules on the SFP-side port version.

Comment: @user10776032 Well that means they have a copper port next to the SFP port and you can only use one or the other.... So you just use the copper port, which **isn't** an SFP port, and don't worry about SFPs.